# .NET debugger for x64

Tags: c#, components, debugging

I would like to implement a [Mini IDE](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/ScriptEditorCtrl.aspx) in my program to write additional modules. I want to include in the Mini IDE the debugger. [That's](http://www.codeproject.com/search.aspx?q=mdbg&sbo=kw) all I was able find about the creation of the debugger. As I understand ICorDebug does not support x64 but my application is written for x64, and so modules should also be written under x64. What can I use to debug the modules under x64?

Comment: It would be a good idea to accept answers to some of your other questions.  You'll get a better response when asking new questions, and you'll get some reputation.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing the fact that mixed mode (interop) debugging with x64 doesn't work with ICorDebug supporting x64.  You can definitely debug x64 bit apps with a managed debugger based on ICorDebug.  Perhaps I am misunderstanding your question.